# Проблемы с XML файлом

Tags: php, xml

есть много XML Файлов типа http://namastebet.com/betradar/NAMASTEBET2016-6-4T09-14-57.XML

у них есть такой параметр как Competitors и в них есть названия двух команд соперников. как можно реализовать добавку их в БД? вот как делаю я но не получается:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<?
//////////
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","logn","pass"); 
mysql_select_db("BD",$db) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset(utf8);
//////////

$conn_id = ftp_connect("Host");
                        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "login", "123456");
                        $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
                        $counts=count($contents);
                        for($i=5;$i<=$counts;$i++)
                        {
                            //echo $contents[$i].'<br>';
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement("betradar/$contents[$i]",null,true);
foreach($xml->Sports->Sport as $Sport)
{   
    $SportName = $Sport->Texts->Text->Value;
    foreach($Sport->Category as $Cat)
    {
        $CatName = $Cat->Texts->Text->Value;
        foreach($Cat->Tournament as $Tournament)
        {
            $TourName = $Tournament->Texts->Text->Value;
            foreach($Tournament->Match as $Cat2)
            {
                $MatchID = $Cat2[BetradarMatchID];
                foreach($Cat2->Fixture->Competitors->Texts as $Cat3)
                {
                    $players = $Cat3->Text->Text->Value;
                }
                foreach($Cat2->Fixture->Competitors as $Players)
                {
                    $Player1 = $Players->Player1->Text->Value;
                    $Player2 = $Players->Player2->Text->Value;
                    $Player3 = $Players->Player3->Text->Value;
                    $Player4 = $Players->Player4->Text->Value;
                }
                foreach($Cat2->Fixture as $Match)
                {
                    $CupRound = $Match->RoundInfo->Cupround;
                    $MatchDate = $Match->DateInfo->MatchDate;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach($Cat->Outright as $CatA)
        {
            $OutRightID = $CatA['BetradarOutrightID'];
            $EventName = $CatA->Fixture->EventInfo->EventName->Texts->Text->Value;
            foreach($CatA->Fixture->Competitors->Texts as $Players2)
                {
                    $OutRightPlayers = $Players2->Text->Text->Value;

                }
        }

    }
        $CheckMatch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Betradar WHERE MatchID='".$MatchID."'");
                $CheckMatchNum = mysql_num_rows($CheckMatch);
                if($CheckMatchNum > 0)
                {
                    //$Up = mysql_query("UPDATE Betradar SET Team2='".$players."', OutT2='".$OutRightPlayers."' WHERE MatchID='".$MatchID."'");
                }
                else
                {
                    $Add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Betradar(`SportName`,`CatName`,`TourName`,`MatchID`,`OutRightID`,`Team1`,`Team2`,`TPlayer1`,`TPlayer2`,`TPlayer3`,`TPlayer4`,`CupRound`,`MatchDate`,`EventName`,`OutT1`,`OutT2`,`FileN`) VALUES('".$SportName."','".$CatName."','".$TourName."','".$MatchID."','".$OutRightID."','".$players."','".$players."','".$Player1."','".$Player2."','".$Player3."','".$Player4."','".$CupRound."','".$MatchDate."','".$EventName."','".$OutRightPlayers."','".$OutRightPlayers."','".$contents[$i]."')") or die(mysql_error());
                    if($add == true)
                    {
                        echo 'ok';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'bed';
                    }
                }       
}
                        }
?>
```

Comment: Есть возможно укоротить XML-файл? Дело в том, что ваше сообщение даже нельзя отформатировать - это приводит к превышению лимита на него, а в таком виде оно просто не читабельно.

Comment: Оставил ссылку!

Comment: ну может есть какой-то выход из данной ситуации